# How did the term "worthless" come by its current definition?

Tags: meaning, etymology

If I were to define the term "worthless," I would define it as "worth LESS" or "worth not a lot."

But the actual [dictionary definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/worthless) is something like "worth zero." That's even less than "worth less" or "worth-not-a-lot."

How did the term come by its actual connotation. Could "less" in this context be a play or derivative of the German "los?" (The German Wertlos has the same meaning as the English worthless.)

Comment: It's _worth_ with a suffix, not a compound of _worth_ and _less_.

Comment: Worthless, senseless, ceaseless, careless, hopeless, thoughtless, pointless and so on, all bear the meaning 'being without the quality', idiomatically. I cannot think of one example which conveys the meaning 'being limited in said quality'. But it is an interesting point and the question provoked the answer below (_leas_ meaning 'devoid') so I have up-voted both question and answer (+1).

Comment: Tom, "-less" is a very common suffix.   (Peerless, matchless, childless etc etc.)  It has no connection at all to the word "less".  It's incredibly commonplace in English that totally unrelated items have the same spelling.

Comment: a better question might be to ask how the suffix '-less' and the word 'less' came to have different meanings.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your definition would be wrong. The **suffix** ***[-less](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-less)*** means:

> 1 (forming adjectives and adverbs from nouns) not having; free from.
> *‘flavourless’
>
> ‘skinless’*
>
> 2 (forming adjectives and adverbs from verbs) not affected by or not
> carrying out the action of the verb.
> *‘fathomless’
>
> ‘tireless’*
>
> **Origin**
> Old English -lēas, from lēas ‘devoid of’.

---

Note that the origin given for the **word** ***[less](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/less)*** is different.

Comment: It is also much used: countless, seamless. Though in countless it means so much. Funny, huh?

Comment: Countless conforms to the explanation given by michael.hor257k. It  means a number not having a countable total, because it is so large that it has not been (or cannot be) counted. There are countless grains of sand on the beach.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think Lambie is well aware of that and was just making a pun.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that, yes, it's totally a cognate with German "-los", which is also from Proto-Germanic [lausaz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/lausaz)

Comment: Exactly, @mattdm. I think it would be hard to find a Germanic language without the suffix.